# Code from Visio Drawing

Tags: vba, uml, visio

Happy Monday Guys,
I have a question about visio.

I have a project where the user can input an UML-Diagram and at the end they receive an SCL-Code (Automation).

I have been thinking about using Visio, since it has UML-Diagram in it. But the question is if it is possible to generate the code from UML-Diagram in Visio. If yes, what is the output from Visio that can be processed?

Thank you

Comment: Visio is a **Drawing** tool, not a **Modeling** tool. Choose the latter one to be able to analyze the model and produce whatever code you need.

Answer (score 0):

A standard for exchanging UML is XMI. It is described in the UML specification, well documented and is handled by most of the applications supporting drawing UML. I'm not sure if Visio can produce it, but Visio (like most MS produces) is rather poor at keeping standards and shouldn't be used as a reference.
So XMI as UML input is probably best solution for you.